# How to dynamically create textblock based on the entries parsed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse down a web API, Based on the entries obtained i want show all bank account transaction (list of all entries) associated with a single account and want to show it in dynamically created text block.
Similar like this:-

[image]

Here is my parser class

```
public class Transaction
{
public string dec { get; set; }
public string amt { get; set; }
public string date { get; set; }
}

public class Loginresponse
{
public List<Transaction> transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Here dec- Description, amt- Amount, i have successfully parsed the web API.

```
<Grid Name="accountdetails" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#66ac22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="456" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="No." Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="66,0,319,0" Text="Date." Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="166,0,140,0" Text="Description" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="364,0,0,0" Text="Amount" Foreground="White"/>
                    <ItemsControl Name="accdetails" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=transaction}" Margin="0,10,0,-440">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding dec}" Foreground="Black" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding amt}" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" Foreground="Black"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
```

My class file:-

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        try
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> parameters = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;
            if (parameters.ContainsKey("key"))
            {
                var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(parameters["key"]);
                this.accdetails.DataContext = root1.loginresponse.transaction;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now i am unable to figure out how to dynamically create textblock and show all this details obtained from parser.
 Any kind of guidance, suggestion, or correct method of writing code with details would be appreciated.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Pivot Title="" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}">

        <phone:PivotItem Header="transactions" FontSize="20">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,420" Background="#f9f9f9">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Name="accountdetails" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#66ac22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="456" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="No." Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="66,0,319,0" Text="Date." Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="166,0,140,0" Text="Description" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="364,0,0,0" Text="Amount" Foreground="White"/>
                    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="5,32,0,-340"
                           Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding no}" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding date}" Foreground="Black" Margin="30,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding dec}" Foreground="Black" Margin="40,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding amt}" Foreground="Black" Margin="120,5,80,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Now i am getting the list of text but i unable to show it properly in the grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Why don't you use a listbox instead?

Declare a Listbox in xaml like this with textblocks text binding your properties.

    <Listbox name ="lstBox">
        <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
            <Listbox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding dec}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
    </Listbox>

Now in cs file.
```

For first 25 entries.

```
List<Type> newList=new List<Type>();

int count =your list.Count;

    if(count >25)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < your list.Count; i++)
       {
        if(i<=24)
        {
          newList.Add(your list[i]};
        }
      }
   }
```

lstBox.ItemSource=newList;

Try this.

Comment: how can i restrict the number of entries to bi displayed ?? I just want to show latest 25 entries only out of all transaction, what should i do???

Comment: you would have to parse the web response you are getting in the form of a list of type as your parser class.

Comment: @amu- thanks for all your answers. I need your help with one more issue. The text in the listbox is kind of scattered need to your help to fix it.

Comment: make the data template properly. The data template designs the look of a list so try improving it.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is to use an `ItemsControl`, this binds to a collection of items and displays each e using the data template you specify.

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=transaction}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dec}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: No data is still displayed. I have updated my code please have a look.

Comment: how can i restrict the number of entries to bi displayed ?? I just want to show latest 25 entries only out of all transaction, what should i do???